# How to load binary data into a script or other HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

I have the need to load binary data, say a ZIP file for example, into a webpage, but it cannot be loaded with AJAX due to the cross-domain policy. Can it be loaded into a `script`/`img`/`link` tag for example somehow?

How would I get access to that raw data to make a blob URL for example?

Comment: Are you not in control of the “remote” site, so that you could allow the request from there (CORS?)

Comment: You can make the browser load the data with a tag, but you wont have access to that data from your script as that would defeat the purpose of the same-origin policy.

Comment: I don't have control over the remote site. I can, for example, load jQuery from one CDN and another script from a different domain and use both together. I just want to load another "script" into the page, and use its raw data from my other scripts

Comment: @Climax Well if you don't have control over the remote server you don't have any right to read its contents, thanks to the same-origin policy. It's up to the remote server to let you read its contents by providing a response header that tells the browser it's OK for your script to see the contents. When you load jQuery you're not reading the contents of the script file, you're telling the browser to load the file and parse the code.

Comment: I would like to do the same thing. But i can't find how. I guess it's not possible...

Answer (score -1):

You could just [change the policy](https://enable-cors.org/).

However since it would be rather difficult to do anything useful with a zip file in javascript, I presume you want the facility to download the target data. So just insert an iframe pointing to the resource.

Comment: There are zip file javascript libs available: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: Also I don't have control over the remote site's CORS

Comment: Then we're not talking about "binary data" or blobs

Comment: It could be, I just used zip as an example. It's not human readable, and the browser doesn't "understand" it.